# Get the memory usage of an Android app from another app

Tags: android, memory

I'm developing an Android app to get the memory usage of another android app at every second.

I start a background service and then run other app using the package name of it. Then I get the PID of that app, and get the `proc/<pid>/smaps` OR `proc/<pid>/stat` OR `proc/<pid>/statm` files to get the memory usage.

Can someone instruct me on how to get the memory usage from that file, or any other method?

Comment: @Nirali Thanks for your efforts to improve SO with your edits. There's really no reason for the bold editing you seem [to](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1691821) [do](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1690550) [in](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1691867) [various](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1697285) [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1697596), though. Please, see [Is editing posts to only introduce bold emphasis acceptable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158564/169503) for more context.